# Using NSPredicate to search for a range of NSStrings

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I am trying to use `NSPredicate` to search `Core Data` for all results that match a number of `NSStrings`. The following works for finding the results with 'a' but how do I set the NSPredicate to find 'a', 'b' and 'c'?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Result ==  'a'"]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Result ==  'a' OR Result ==  'b' OR Result ==  'c'"]];
```

OR

> EDIT:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.Result IN %@",[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c", nil]];
```

Comment: That simple - thanks. Is it possible to set up an array containing 'a','b' and 'c' for example and setting the predicate to use the array?

Answer (score 0):

The another way to search the string is using [Regular Expression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html). Try this:-

```
NSString *yourString = @"Insert your String here";
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression         
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[a|b|c]"
    options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInasensitive
    error:&error];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:yourString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourString length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
    // your code here
}];
```